# CRM + Invoicing/Billing + Ticketing for a small web design company

Tags: php, service

I am currently using ActiveCollab but it lacks the typical CRM features. I can't even keep notes about a customer saved in one place.

What I am looking for is a simple but efficient CRM application that allows me to store all the (potential) customers along with their phone calls noted down, contracts, agreements.

On the billing end, I should be able to keep track of invoices and payments, along with a bit of sales reports.

A great extra would be a ticket support feature but not really necessary

I looked at VTiger and SugarCRM at first. Though, they look too complex on the sales/campaigns end but completely lack the billing side.

Do you have some good apps/services to suggest? :) Any programming language or OS would do. Both paid and free.

Thanks Mike

Answer (score 1):

WHMCS ticks all of those boxes.

Invoicing, billing, customer notes, support tickets, knowledgebase etc. It is paid for but a few resellers do offer it as part of their package, [EZPZHosting](http://ezpzhosting.co.uk/) are one.

I have just moved over to it from Helm and after a bit of a bedding in period I am loving it. All my domain names are organsied and billed automatically, it links in via API's to the big domain resellers, it does one off invoices, splits, loads of features as well as the support ticket and knowledgebase. Love it.

Comment: We don't offer any hosting/domain registration yet.. but it looks like a very complete platform. Do you think it's worth using it as a webdesign/development companyù?

Comment: Simple answer: yes. Long answer: yes because for us ( a small web design & hosting company) it seems to be a complete and feature rich application. The price is not too steep either: $324 or £199 in our money for the full life time unbranded licence (and even the unlicensed branded version is very subtle).

Comment: It integrates seamlessly with Web Host Manager allowing customers to signup up manually or automatically, register domains, create hosting accounts etc, We have a complete customer management tool with billing, knowledgebase, support tickets. It uses Smarty Tags so is easy to edit and integrate with your existing site, the list just goes on.

We especially like the way it integrates with our Domain Reseller (NetEarthOne) and manages our domain renewals, issuing reminders to customers and running the entire billing/renewal/emails when a customer pays so we don't have to do anything manually.

Comment: It is still early days for us in terms of our usage of WHMCS but we are delighted with it. The support is excellent although the forum is a little slow and often questions do go unanswered.

Comment: NOTE: Had to split the answer as comments are limited in size.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Infusionsoft? It's kind of expensive, but it does both CRM and Billing. I don't think it does tracking natively, but it has a great API, so it would be pretty easy to hook up with some other bug tracker.

The only other one I have used is Sugar, which is actually very flexible and covers projects and bug tracking nicely, but as you mentioned, doesn't have billing. When I've needed to use sugar for billing, I had to write a script that syncs sugar data with another software.

Not really a good answer. good luck finding something.